# SQL Server secure JDBC connection without reconfiguring SQL Server for secure connections

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

How to connect SQL Server database instance via JDBC securely without altering the configuration of SQL Server where other connections access the server insecurely and it is not possible to change the configuration of the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some trouble connecting to SQL Server via Java JDBC using encryption. The method below supports a secure connection where the validity of the certificate is not checked. SQL Server will issue the certificate and use encryption. This method does not require other connections to the database to be secure and also does not require changes to the database server.

Just substitute your IP:port combination and your database instance in the statement below

```
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=yourDBname;" + 
    "integratedSecurity=false;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```